# javascript/jquery function to run only after the previous one has completed execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on a simple jquery animation where I have defined two functions as runit(); and runit2().

What I need is to execute runit2() only after runit() has finished execution but the problem is both seems to be executing at the same time.

I am including a rough fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5444s/

Can anyone help please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `runit2()` call in the `item2.fadeOut()` callback function. As `item2.fadeOut` is called at the end of your `runit()` function, `runit2()` will be executed after `runit();`
Replace your `runit()` function by :

```
function runit(){
    var b = fixit("container3");
    item1.myFunction();
    item1.animate({left:"-="+b+"px",top:"-=140px"},"fast");
    item2.fadeOut(500,function(){
        $(this).css('zIndex','-1');
        runit2();
    });
}
```

Comment: But was looking for some explanation why it didn't worked earlier, any clues?? Also is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: In the code you've posted on jsfiddle the syntax of `setTimeout` function is not respected, try `setTimeout(function(){ runit2(); },3000);` or `setTimeout("runit2",3000);` to get it work, but if the execution of the `runit()` function take more than `3000ms` `runit2()` will not be executed after `runit()`